# NiFi Custom Processor with Banned Dependency Error

Tags: java, maven, apache-nifi

I'm building a custom processor that has a dependency on org.json. When I try to build the nar I get a maven error related to a "Banned Depency" (Apache NiFi 1.16.3).

I can see in the Apache NiFi project POM file the enforcer is banning `org.json` as a dependency, but I don't understand why.

I've tried adding `<scope>provided</scope>` to my project for that dependency and when I do, the project builds fine, but... the processor throws an error with a 'class not found' exception.

What is the work around for this?